# Find a limes - function with 2 variables

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

1)$ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1  y \to 1} (2y-x)^{\frac{1}{\sin(2y-x-1)}}$

2)$ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0  y \to 1} (2x+y)^{\operatorname{ctg}(2x+y-1)}$

Ok, how to find a limes or prove that it doesn't exist? Is this any scheme or sth like that?

Answer (score 1):

$$z=2x-y$$
$$ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1  y \to 1} (2y-x)^{\frac{1}{\sin(2y-x-1)}}=\displaystyle \lim_{z \to 1 } z^{\frac{1}{\sin(z-1)}}=\displaystyle \lim_{z \to 1 } e^{ \ln z^{\frac{1}{\sin(z-1)}}}=\displaystyle \lim_{z \to 1 } e^{ \frac{\ln z}{\sin(z-1)}}.$$
Use l'Hopital's rule to evaluate the limit. We have
$$ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1  y \to 1} (2y-x)^{\frac{1}{\sin(2y-x-1)}}=\displaystyle  e^{ \lim_{z \to 1 }\frac{1}{z\cos(z-1)}}=e.$$
Use this scheme for find the second limit.

Comment: Yeah! The first one - perfecto!:)
But what is the limes of z in the second one? x→0 y→1
z-> ?

Comment: @user116011 Put $z=2x+y.$ If $x=0, y=1$ then $z=2\cdot 0+1=1$

Comment: true, but what about cotangens? It doesn't exist ctg0

Comment: But $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} Ctg z=\infty.$ Use $Ctg z=\frac{\cos z}{\sin z}.$ You will get the first one.